# Как принимать post Weebhook c aiogram? python

Tags: python, aiogram, post, aiohttp, webhook

Есть определенный код с ботом через aiogram. Как можно принимать post Weebhook? Пробовал через flask но с ним понятно бот не работает(потому что flask синхронный фреймворк). Знаю что можно через aiohttp, но не понял как именно принимать данные. ip на ПК белый